# Is it possible to connect to ec2 instance as root user by using the PEM file?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lamp

I'm trying to connect to an EC2 AWS instance but when I tried to install PHPMYADMIN the linux console asks me for the root user password, which I forgot about. Could anyone please know how to use .PEM file to login as the root user? 
I tried sudo su command but it still asks me for the root user.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

***Disclaimer:*** It is not recommended to login as root.

But still if you want to, then:

1. Allow `PermitRootLogin` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
2. Restart SSH service
3. you need to paste the existing public key which is in the `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` to `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Now you should be able to login as root using the .pem key.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tried to download the sshd_config file to modify it as you suggested using Bitvise SSH Client but the download fails. It says: "Transfer failed. Opening remote file failed: Permission denied".

Answer (score 1):

You don't need your root password if you are running `sudo su -`, you need the password of the user you are running the sudo command as. Provided that the user has sudo privileges as root. Then you can just run as root:

```
yum install phpmyadmin
```

Comment: I would suggest simply `sudo yum install phpmyadmin`

Comment: @Rico. Thanks for your reply. Actually when type the command sudo su -, as you suggested, it's still asks me for the root's password.

Comment: @Ben Whaley. I tried your command but it still asks me for the root pass.